# c#.net Exception handling best practice

Tags: exception

Could someone please provide me with an example of best practices for exception handling in c#.net?

Especially please clarify the following?

1.When to:

> a. Throw b. Rethrow  c. Do nothing d. nullException

1. Is it ok to wrap every logic inside a function with in try and catch? If not when should we?
2. Where should i catch and handle exception in asp.net mvc? i.e. global.asax, BLL, DLL or helper methods?
3. When to wrap the exceptin within inner exception?

Comment: please see link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: here is another one on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx